# show Admob interstitial ads every button click?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

in this image  there is 8 buttons . now iam using test ads units on this app. this activity i have 8 buttons and every buttons are linked with there targeted activity . my problem is when i click the any button of this 8 it show the admob  interstitial ads and send to the targeted activity but when i closed the targeted activity and back to main_activity again and click any button of this 8 buttons the admo interstitial ads is not showing but on button click it open  the targeted activity. i want to show  admob interstitial ads on everytime when the buttons are clicked. how can is do this?

```
    // Admob Firebase
    AdView myadview = new AdView(this);
    // AdRequest smartBanner
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    // Admob Intarsital
    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

private void initialize() {
    linear1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
    linear2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear2);
    linear3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear3);
    linear4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear4);
    button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
    button13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
    button14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
    button15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
    button16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button16);
    textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _v) {
            b.setClass(getApplicationContext(), DhakaActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    });
    button10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _v) {
            b.setClass(getApplicationContext(), KhulnaActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    });
    button11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _v) {
            b.setClass(getApplicationContext(), RoungpurActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    });
    button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _v) {
            b.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SeyletActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    });
    button13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _v) {
            b.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ChitagongActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    });
    button14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _v) {
            b.setClass(getApplicationContext(), BorishalActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    });
    button15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _v) {
            b.setClass(getApplicationContext(), RajshashiActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    });
    button16.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _v) {
            b.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ChitagongActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                    // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                    // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    // Code to be executed when when the interstitial ad is closed.
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

[image main_activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfbM3.png)

Answer (score 0):

put the section of codes which loads an adview in onResume method of your activity. So that every time the activity is resumed load a new ad.

```
 // Admob Firebase
AdView myadview = new AdView(this);
// AdRequest smartBanner
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
// Admob Intarsital
MobileAds.initialize(this,
        "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

put these in onResume method